# Angularjs - how to see if a value is in array?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a model similar to this one:

```
model = [
 {
   name: 'Chris',
   age: '29',
   approvedBy: ['id1', 'id2', 'id3']
 },
 {
   // repeat...
 }
]
```

in my view I have a ng-repeat for the model and there is a button to approve or disapprove the user.

Basically other users can approve or disapprove, if previously approved, the user. Quite similar to like or unlike a FB post.

```
<div ng-repeat='user in model'>
  <p>Name: {{user.name}} - Age: {{user.age}}</p>
  <p>Approved by {{user.approvedBy.length}} users.</p>
  <button>Approve {{user.name}}</button>
</div>
```

It works fine, so I can approve and disapprove the user but I can not figure out how can I change the text of **Approve**.

I wish it to be **Disapprove** if has already been approved by the user in the session.

I'm looking for something like `indexOf` to create an inline if... or a filter...

It should look like:

```
<button>(user.approvedBy.indexOf(currentUserId)) ? 'Disapprove' : 'Approve'</button>
```

How can I create something like that in Angularjs?

Comment: What you've tried should work, at least if [`Array.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) is used correctly (pay attention to the return value).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple approach would be:

Add a custom filter to the controller and then use it in the view:

**In controller:**

```
$scope.model = [...];
$scope.approveTextFilter = function (user) {
   return user.approvedBy.indexOf(currentUserId) !== -1 ? 'Disapprove' : 'Approve';
};
```

**In view:**

```
<div ng-repeat='user in model'>
   ...
   ...
   <button ng-bind="user | filter:approveTextFilter"></button>
</div>
```